# Custom size for custom UIView

Tags: swift, uiview

I want to create a custom UIView that determines the height of the frame based on the NSLayoutConstraints set in the custom UIView.

For example I want to create a calendar view which may have 5 ~ 6 rows of weeks in month. The height will vary depending on how many weeks there are in a month.

Since the custom view will determine the rows depending on the calendar data assigned to it, I want the custom view to resize itself in the superview.

I am currently using XIB file to implement the custom view and assigning a UIView implementation to the File Owner, but when I add the view to the superview setting the offset and width to the custom UIView, the height is not resized itself as intended.

What should I implement so that the height can be resized in its superview?

Comment: Use a scrollview with stack views inside.

Comment: @AMAN77 Are you suggesting that the stack view should contain the calendar custom view? I think you misunderstood my question. When the calendar custom view is added to the superview through coding, the frame height is 0 and is not resized based on the custom view NSLayoutConstraints which should be width / 7 * rows of month.

Comment: you just need to setup your constraints properly, the calander view should have all constraints to allow it to calculate its height and dont set a height on the calander view from the parent, instead set a minimum height and let it calculate itself based on the content

Comment: @Scriptable How should I implement it? Current custom views child view is already has the necessary constraints. But as soon as I set the height to be same as child view, Xcode complains that there is a conflict in the constraints.

Comment: personally I would set the constraints in code. But you will need to use the greaterThanOrEqual or lessThanOrEqual constraint attributes instead of setting specific height. I'll see if i can provide an example shortly when i get a break